# como puedo validar dos fechas dentro de un datepicker en filament 3.x

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Estoy haciendo un modulo donde solo me queda consultar por fecha, es facil con filament la verdad, pero necesito validar que las fechas dadas no excedan de 15 dias, sorprendentemente, ChatGPT no tiene informacion acerca de eso.
Este es el código:

```
->filters([
            //
            SelectFilter::make('status')
                ->options([
                    '0' => 'Sin enviar',
                    '1' => 'En Cola',
                    '2' => 'Enviados',
                    '3' => 'Detenidos'
                ])
                ->label('Estatus de Envio'),
            
            Filter::make('fechaCola')
            ->form([
                DatePicker::make('fechaCola_from')
                            ->default(date('d/m/Y'))
                            ->native(false)
                            ->label('Fecha desde')
                            ->maxDate(now()),
                DatePicker::make('fechaCola_last')
                            ->default(date('d/m/Y'))
                            ->maxDate(now())
                            ->afterOrEqual('fechaCola_from')
                            ->label('Fecha hasta')
                            ->native(false)
            ])
            ->query(function (Builder $query, array $data): Builder{
                return $query
                        ->when(
                            $data['fechaCola_from'] ?? null,
                            fn (Builder $query, $date): Builder => $query->whereDate('fechaCola', '>=', $date),
                        )
                        ->when(
                            $data['fechaCola_last'] ?? null,
                            fn (Builder $query, $date): Builder => $query->whereDate('fechaCola', '<=', $date)
                        );
            })
        ])
```

lo que quiero es validar que la fecha no pase de 15 dias, y mostrarle una notificacion al usuario indicandole que ha excedido el rango maximo. gracias de antemano.